# SessionVariable parametrised in Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, cookies, webrequest

I want to pass a variable to `SessionVariable` as an argument, so that I can use any name for the `SessionObject` so that I can test/send to other functions, and not happy it is being hardcoded... i.e. Pass `$TCSessionVar` instead of a hardcoded `TCSessionVar` argument.

```
$Response= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $TeamCityUrl `
   -SessionVariable $TCSessionVar -Method `
   Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $Encoded"}

$ReturnObject =New-Object PSCustomObject @{
    SessionVar=[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]$TCSessionVar
    Response=$Response
}
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession".

--Note: I can create the WebReuestSessionObject from the response, but then SessionVariable is pointless..

```
$TCCookieName="TCSESSIONID"
$Cookies=$Response.Headers.'set-cookie'
$TCCookie= $cookies.Split(";")| Where-Object {$_ -match $TCCookieName}
$CookieName=$TCCookie.Split("=")[0]
$CookieValue=$TCCookie.Split("=")[1]
$TCSession = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie 
$cookie.Name = $CookieName
$cookie.Value = $CookieValue
$cookie.Domain=([uri]$TeamCityUrl).Host
$TCSession.Cookies.Add($cookie);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if I
    `-SessionVariable (get-variable -name "TCSessionVar" -ValueOnly)` and get the response as: `(get-variable -name (get-variable "TCSessionVar" -valueonly) -valueonly)`

```
$Response= Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $TeamCityUrl -SessionVariable (get-variable -name "TCSessionVar" -ValueOnly) -Method Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $Encoded"}
$ReturnObject =New-Object PSCustomObject @{
        SessionVar=[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession](get-variable -name (get-variable "TCSessionVar" -valueonly) -valueonly)
        Response=$Response
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It works!

```
$sess = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$IWRParams = @{
    SessionVariable = Get-Variable -name sess -ValueOnly
    Method = 'GET'
    Uri = "$($Server)/login"
    Headers = @{'X-Redmine-API-Key'=$Key}
}
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest @IWRParams
$this.CSRFToken = $Response.Forms.Fields['authenticity_token']
$this.Session = Get-Variable -name $sess -ValueOnly
```